# Conic Sections Checking my solution: My Foci seams to be bigger than my Vertices (I think there is something wrong with my solution)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

Which one is my error? Pls help!

[image: My solution photo]

Comment: take it as an exercise, try to typeset your question using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553). It doesn't have to be perfect and the rest will try to edit to make your post better as well, but yup, give it a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two mistakes.

$(x+1)^2+(2y-4)^2 = 4$ should be

$\displaystyle \small \frac{(x+1)^2}{4}+\frac{(y-2)^2}{1} = 1$

$c^2 = a^2-b^2 = 3 \implies c = \pm \sqrt3$

You also write $c^2 = a^2+b^2$ but that is not correct.

Given the center, the foci will be $(-1 \pm \sqrt3, 2)$

Comment: What happens to the factored out "2" from (2−4)^2?

Comment: you should have factored out $4$, not $2$. Look at it this way $4y^2-16y+16 = 4(y^2-4y+4) = 4(y-2)^2$

Comment: Thanks so much! I forgot to square the 2 haha

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$(2y-4)^2 \ne 2(y-2)^2$$

It should be

$$(2y-4)^2=4(y-2)^2$$

Comment: Where did the "4" come from 4(−2)^2?

Comment: $$(2y-4)^2 = [2(y-2)]^2=2^2 (y-2)^2$$

Comment: Thank you! :) got it.